# Matplotlib: How to draw bars within table cells?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Excel has a feature to draw data bars inside table cells.
Conditional Formatting >> Data Bars.

See the image.

[image: bars within spreadsheet cells]

How to programmatically create a similar result with matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will either have to draw things manually, or tweak a bar plot a little bit. A quick 'n dirty example:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

def remove_ax():
    ax=pl.gca()
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

names  = ['Bill','John','Mark']
weight = [155,225,180]
age    = [30,40,50]

dh = 0.8
yloc = np.arange(3) 

pl.figure()
ax=pl.subplot(121)
remove_ax()
pl.title('Weight')
pl.barh(yloc-dh/2, weight, dh, alpha=0.4)
xloc = ax.get_xlim()[-1] - 0.05 * (ax.get_xlim()[-1] - ax.get_xlim()[0])
for i in range(len(weight)):
    pl.text(xloc, yloc[i], '{}'.format(weight[i]), va='center', ha='right', size=18)
ax.set_yticks(yloc)
ax.set_yticklabels(names)
ax.tick_params(labelbottom='off')  

ax=pl.subplot(122)
remove_ax()
pl.title('Age')
pl.barh(yloc-dh/2, age, dh, alpha=0.4)
xloc = ax.get_xlim()[-1] - 0.05 * (ax.get_xlim()[-1] - ax.get_xlim()[0])
for i in range(len(weight)):
    pl.text(xloc, yloc[i], '{}'.format(age[i]), va='center', ha='right', size=18)
ax.set_yticks(yloc)
ax.tick_params(labelleft='off')  
ax.tick_params(labelbottom='off')
```